# Once I get all the tables with a certain column present, how can I get all the rows associated with said tables?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following SQL for ORACLE (10g)

```
select origTabCols.owner, origTabCols.table_name, 
(select COUNT(*) from all_tab_columns 
    where MARKET_ID = 1) as MarketCount
from all_tab_columns origTabCols
where origTabCols.column_name = 'MARKET_ID' 
group by origTabCols.owner, origTabCols.table_name
order by origTabCols.table_name asc;
```

this part gets all tables with a column MARKET_ID

```
select owner, table_name from all_tab_columns
where column_name = 'MARKET_ID' 
order by table_name;
```

but now, I want all the rows in tables with column MARKET_ID = 1 and how many ROWS of MARKET_ID = 1 per result set.

The result should look like this:

```
ID   |   OWNER       | TABLE_NAME      | ROWS_PER_TABLE
-----------------------------------------------------
1        DBA           TABLE_1           45
2        DBA           TABLE_2           452
3        DBA           TABLE_3           13
4        DBA           TABLE_4           95
```

Further expanding this, if there's a FOREIGN KEY to a child table, where MARKET_ID = 1, I need to know that too so I can perform a CASCADING DELETE

That would look like this...

```
ID   |   OWNER       | TABLE_NAME      | ROWS_PER_TABLE    | FOREIGN_KEY | NUM_ROWS
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1        DBA           TABLE_1           45                  FK_ID_1         3
2        DBA           TABLE_2           452                 FK_ID_2         1556 
3        DBA           TABLE_3           13                  FK_ID_3         365   
4        DBA           TABLE_4           95                  FK_ID_4         22
```

Thank you for your assistance.

**UPDATE:**

I've really expanded the call to reflect the solution in PL/SQL

All that's left is to get the number of ROWS in said child tables that's it...

```
set serveroutput on;

 

DECLARE
parent_table_name VARCHAR2(30) := 'AGREEMENT';
sql_stmt VARCHAR2(2000);
cursor_child_tables SYS_REFCURSOR;
child_table_name VARCHAR2(30);
column_name varchar(100);

 

BEGIN
  OPEN cursor_child_tables FOR
    SELECT C.table_name
    FROM all_constraints C
    JOIN all_cons_columns CC ON C.constraint_name = CC.constraint_name
    WHERE C.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME IN (
      SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME from all_constraints WHERE table_name=parent_table_name
    ) 
    AND C.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'R';

LOOP
  FETCH cursor_child_tables INTO child_table_name;
  EXIT WHEN cursor_child_tables%NOTFOUND;

  sql_stmt := 'SELECT * FROM ' || child_table_name;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Child_Table: ' || child_table_name);
  DECLARE
    cursor_columns SYS_REFCURSOR;
  BEGIN

    OPEN cursor_columns FOR
      SELECT column_name
      FROM all_tab_columns
      WHERE table_name = child_table_name;

      LOOP 
        FETCH cursor_columns INTO column_name;
        EXIT WHEN cursor_columns%NOTFOUND;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE cursor_columns;
    END;

    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cursor_child_tables;
  END;
```

**UPDATE 2:**

All, we have no choice but to make this work with SQL... So, I've dumbed it down to three steps:

What I want to do is take STEP 1 and insert it into where I have ACCT_CODE in STEP 2 as a loop, then when I find the child tables, then I simply need to continue the loop for TBL1 - 'TBL-....' and display all the records in the output.

The total number of possible PARENT tables will not exceed 31 out of a total of 120 TABLES in the DB. ACCT_CODE has 4 CHILD tables in this example and 1 ROW for TBL1. TBL2 - TBL4 could be 1 - "n"

I'm close.

```
-- STEP 1
select owner, table_name from all_tab_columns
where column_name = 'MARKET_ID' 
order by table_name;

-- STEP 2
set serveroutput on;
DECLARE
parent_table_name VARCHAR2(30) := 'ACCT_CODE';

--CHILD TABLES for ACCT_CODE
--Child_Table: TBL1
--Child_Table: TBL2
--Child_Table: TBL3
--Child_Table: TBL4

sql_stmt VARCHAR2(2000);
cursor_child_tables SYS_REFCURSOR;
child_table_name VARCHAR2(30);
column_name varchar(100);

BEGIN
  OPEN cursor_child_tables FOR
    SELECT C.table_name
    FROM all_constraints C
    JOIN all_cons_columns CC ON C.constraint_name = CC.constraint_name
    WHERE C.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME IN (
      SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME from all_constraints WHERE table_name=parent_table_name
    ) 
    AND C.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'R';

LOOP
  FETCH cursor_child_tables INTO child_table_name;
  EXIT WHEN cursor_child_tables%NOTFOUND;

  sql_stmt := 'SELECT * FROM ' || child_table_name;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Child_Table: ' || child_table_name);
  DECLARE
    cursor_columns SYS_REFCURSOR;
  BEGIN

    OPEN cursor_columns FOR
      SELECT column_name
      FROM all_tab_columns
      WHERE table_name = child_table_name;

      LOOP 
        FETCH cursor_columns INTO column_name;
        EXIT WHEN cursor_columns%NOTFOUND;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE cursor_columns;
    END;

    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cursor_child_tables;
  END;
  
  
  -- STEP 3
  select * from ACCT_CODE
  where MARKET_ID = 1;
```

Comment: Just define your FKs ON DELETE CASCADE and you won't have to do this kind of dictionary work. Is there a reason why this won't work for you? We can provide a workaround to implement your own cascading delete but it's hardly worth the complexity required when Oracle has given this feature built-in.

Comment: You are correct... and it's implemented as it was NO ACTION... but we simply need this for allowing the customer to 'SEE" what we are facing before firing the SQL to actually delete these records

Comment: You'd have to write a recursive procedure that gets FK constraints from `all_constraints` using an `r_constraint_name` of any P or U constraint on the parent table being deleted from. For each child FK, use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` to run a dynamic select on the table and column or set of columns in question (FKs can be across more than one column, per `all_cons_columns`) looking for the value/values in question. Then for each table found, you'd have to recurse to look for children of the children, and so on until there is no deeper level. That's quite a complex task. Not worth it in my opinion.

Comment: Or you can drop and recreate those existin FKs with ON DELETE CASCADE, create a delete trigger with autonomous_transaction pragma on every table that does an dbms_output.put_line or places an entry into a custom log table indicating the record being deleted (and then commits), then do you top-level-delete and then rollback to undo the work. You'll get a full list of what it would delete. When you are ready, redo but commit at the end instead of rollback. Still it's a lot of work to set up all those triggers. This is hard because nobody does this kind of thing.

Comment: May I kindly get an example of how to simply show what "will be" deleted so then I can export that to a .csv.  That's all I want to achieve right now.  But all of your suggestions are great.

Comment: This works for showing what tables have MARKET_ID, select owner, table_name from all_tab_columns
where column_name = 'MARKET_ID' 
order by table_name; But I need to show the rest and that's where I'm having a wee bit of challenge.  Thank you,

Comment: Is there a reason that this needs to be done in SQL?  Theoretically, it's probably possible but you'd need to go back and see what XML Query options were available in 10g.  And then you're in the realm of SQL statements that a very, very small fraction of developers are going to be able to understand and maintain.  It would make vastly more sense to use PL/SQL here assuming you are able to create stored procedures, objects, etc. in your database.

Comment: Hmmm that's a good point but I'm an MS SQL Server person, not much of PL/SQL... so, a solution I can vote for it.

Comment: The customer wants to validate all the data first, prior to marking for deletion, hence, why I need to do this first.... it's what they want...

Comment: Sounds to me like a one-off need. I'd say gather the tables manually, create the SQL scripts manually to get the counts, and execute manually. Coding something like this isn't worth it.

Comment: Roger that. Thank you

Comment: Oracle 10g? Really? That DBMS is twenty years old and ran out of support many, many years ago. You shouldn't use such an old software.

Comment: Yeah, well, that's what the customer is using

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner, the reality is that many companies are saddled with apps whose vendors are gone or out of support and which cannot therefore certify that their apps would work on a newer version. There's no choice but to keep it running as-is on life-support as long as the function it fulfills is still needed. Few of us have the luxury of having only in-support versions running. We've got dozens of 8i out there, even one 8.0.1. Can't pull the plug if it's serving a business need and can't upgrade if it's not supported anymore. The reality is that folks often have to work with many versions.

Comment: NOTE: This is ORACLE 12 - if this helps... it's not 10g

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but think you could collect all that you need except number of rows in tables where MARKET_ID = 1. For that part you'll need dynamic sql and that means using PL/SQL. Anyway maybe you could get something usefull from the code below.
First some dummy sample data to work with:

```sql
Create Table T1_MARKETS(  MARKET_ID Number, MARKET_NAME VarChar2(32), PRIMARY KEY(MARKET_ID) );
Insert Into T1_MARKETS VALUES(1, 'EUROPE');
Insert Into T1_MARKETS VALUES(2, 'AMERICAS');
Commit;
--
Create Table T2_STATES(   STATE_ID Number, STATE_NAME VarChar2(32), MARKET_ID Number, PRIMARY KEY(STATE_ID),
                          FOREIGN KEY(MARKET_ID) REFERENCES T1_MARKETS(MARKET_ID) );
Insert Into T2_STATES VALUES(1, 'France', 1);
Insert Into T2_STATES VALUES(2, 'Germany', 1);
Insert Into T2_STATES VALUES(3, 'Croatia', 1);
Insert Into T2_STATES VALUES(4, 'Canada', 2);
Insert Into T2_STATES VALUES(5, 'Argentina', 2);
Commit;
--
Create Table T3_CITIES(   CITY_ID Number, CITY_NAME VarChar2(32), MARKET_ID Number, STATE_ID Number, PRIMARY KEY(CITY_ID),
                          FOREIGN KEY(MARKET_ID) REFERENCES T1_MARKETS(MARKET_ID),
                          FOREIGN KEY(STATE_ID) REFERENCES T2_STATES(STATE_ID) );
Insert Into T3_CITIES VALUES(1, 'Paris', 1, 1);
Insert Into T3_CITIES VALUES(2, 'Nantes', 1, 1);
Insert Into T3_CITIES VALUES(3, 'Berlin', 1, 2);
Insert Into T3_CITIES VALUES(4, 'Leipzig', 1, 2);
Insert Into T3_CITIES VALUES(5, 'Zagreb', 1, 3);
Insert Into T3_CITIES VALUES(6, 'Vancouver', 2, 4);
Insert Into T3_CITIES VALUES(7, 'Buenos Aires', 2, 5);
Commit;
--
Create Table T4_CUSTOMERS(CUSTOMER_ID Number, CUSTOMER_NAME VarChar2(32), MARKET_ID Number, STATE_ID Number, CITY_ID Number, PRIMARY KEY(CUSTOMER_ID),
                          FOREIGN KEY(MARKET_ID) REFERENCES T1_MARKETS(MARKET_ID),
                          FOREIGN KEY(STATE_ID) REFERENCES T2_STATES(STATE_ID),
                          FOREIGN KEY(CITY_ID) REFERENCES T3_CITIES(CITY_ID) );
Insert Into T4_CUSTOMERS VALUES(1, 'Sell it all inc FR', 1, 1, 1);
Insert Into T4_CUSTOMERS VALUES(2, 'Sell it all inc DE', 1, 2, 3);
Insert Into T4_CUSTOMERS VALUES(3, 'Sell it all inc HR', 1, 3, 5);
Insert Into T4_CUSTOMERS VALUES(4, 'Sell it all inc CA', 2, 4, 6);
Insert Into T4_CUSTOMERS VALUES(5, 'Sell it all inc AR', 2, 5, 7);
Commit;
--  -------------------------------------------------------------
--  Customers Data:
--
Select c.CUSTOMER_NAME, cty.CITY_NAME, s.STATE_NAME, m.MARKET_NAME
From T4_CUSTOMERS c
Inner Join T3_CITIES cty ON(cty.CITY_ID = c.CITY_ID)
Inner Join T2_STATES s ON(s.STATE_ID = c.STATE_ID)
Inner Join T1_MARKETS m on(m.MARKET_ID = c.MARKET_ID)
--
--  CUSTOMER_NAME            CITY_NAME      STATE_NAME     MARKET_NAME                     
--  -----------------------  -------------  -------------  -------------
--  Sell it all inc FR       Paris          France         EUROPE       
--  Sell it all inc DE       Berlin         Germany        EUROPE       
--  Sell it all inc HR       Zagreb         Croatia        EUROPE     
--  Sell it all inc CA       Vancouver      Canada         AMERICAS     
--  Sell it all inc AR       Buenos Aires   Argentina      AMERICAS  
--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--
```

Create a CTE (named it grid) that will collect tables with MARKET_ID column and foreign keys associated with the tables.

```sql
WITH
    grid AS
        (   Select      t.OWNER, t.TABLE_NAME "PK_TABLE", t.NUM_ROWS "PK_TABLE_ROWS", 
                        kc0.COLUMN_NAME "PK_COLUMN", kc0.CONSTRAINT_NAME "PK_NAME",
                        k1.TABLE_NAME "FK_TABLE", t1.NUM_ROWS "FK_TABLE_ROWS",
                        kc1.COLUMN_NAME "FK_COLUMN", kc1.CONSTRAINT_NAME "FK_NAME",
                        k1.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME "REFERENCED_PK_NAME"
            From        all_tables t 
            Inner Join  all_tab_columns c ON(c.OWNER = t.OWNER And c.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME)
            Left Join   all_constraints k0 ON(k0.OWNER = t.OWNER And k0.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME And k0.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'P')
            Left Join   all_cons_columns kc0 ON(kc0.OWNER = t.OWNER And kc0.CONSTRAINT_NAME = k0.CONSTRAINT_NAME)
            Left Join   all_constraints k1 ON(k1.OWNER = t.OWNER And k1.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'R' And k1.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME = k0.CONSTRAINT_NAME)
            Left Join   all_cons_columns kc1 ON(kc1.OWNER = k1.OWNER And kc1.CONSTRAINT_NAME = k1.CONSTRAINT_NAME)
            Left Join   all_tables t1 ON(t1.OWNER = k1.OWNER And t1.TABLE_NAME = k1.TABLE_NAME)
            Where       c.COLUMN_NAME = 'MARKET_ID' 
            Order By    t.TABLE_NAME
        )
/*
OWNER   PK_TABLE     PK_TABLE_ROWS  PK_COLUMN     PK_NAME       FK_TABLE        FK_TABLE_ROWS   FK_COLUMN   FK_NAME         REFERENCED_PK_NAME
------  ----------  --------------  ------------  ------------  -------------  --------------   ----------  --------------  ------------------
USER_1  T1_MARKETS              2   MARKET_ID     SYS_C0021837  T3_CITIES                   7   MARKET_ID   SYS_C0021841    SYS_C0021837
USER_1  T1_MARKETS              2   MARKET_ID     SYS_C0021837  T4_CUSTOMERS                5   MARKET_ID   SYS_C0021844    SYS_C0021837
USER_1  T1_MARKETS              2   MARKET_ID     SYS_C0021837  T2_STATES                   5   MARKET_ID   SYS_C0021839    SYS_C0021837
USER_1  T2_STATES               5   STATE_ID      SYS_C0021838  T4_CUSTOMERS                5   STATE_ID    SYS_C0021845    SYS_C0021838
USER_1  T2_STATES               5   STATE_ID      SYS_C0021838  T3_CITIES                   7   STATE_ID    SYS_C0021842    SYS_C0021838
USER_1  T3_CITIES               7   CITY_ID       SYS_C0021840  T4_CUSTOMERS                5   CITY_ID     SYS_C0021846    SYS_C0021840
USER_1  T4_CUSTOMERS            5   CUSTOMER_ID   SYS_C0021843                  
*/
```

With this result you can have the tables and their PK - FK relations. Here is the code that gives you those relations and prepares the dynamic sql statements to use with PL/SQL so you could get the rows with MARKET_ID = 1.

```sql
Select      OWNER "OWNER", 
            PK_TABLE "TABLE_NAME", 
            PK_TABLE_ROWS "TABLE_ROWS", 
            LISTAGG(Distinct FK_TABLE, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (Order By FK_TABLE) "REFERENCED_BY_TABLES",
            LISTAGG(Distinct FK_NAME, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (Order By FK_TABLE) "REFERENCED_BY_FK_NAMES",
            LISTAGG(Distinct Case When PK_COLUMN = 'MARKET_ID' Then FK_TABLE End, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (Order By FK_TABLE) "REFERENCED_BY_TABLES_VIA_MARKET_ID",
            'Select Count(*) "ROWS_WHERE_MARKET_ID_IS_1" From ' || PK_TABLE || ' Where MARKET_ID = 1' "SQL_TABLE_MARKET_ID_1_ROWS"
From        grid
Where       Nvl(REFERENCED_PK_NAME, PK_NAME) = PK_NAME
Group By    OWNER, PK_TABLE, PK_TABLE_ROWS, Nvl(REFERENCED_PK_NAME, PK_NAME)
Order By    PK_TABLE
/*
OWNER   TABLE_NAME     TABLE_ROWS   REFERENCED_BY_TABLES                 REFERENCED_BY_FK_NAMES                     REFERENCED_BY_TABLES_VIA_MARKET_ID  SQL_TABLE_MARKET_ID_1_ROWS
------  ------------  -----------   ----------------------------------  ------------------------------------------  ----------------------------------  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
USER_1  T1_MARKETS              2   T2_STATES, T3_CITIES, T4_CUSTOMERS  SYS_C0021839, SYS_C0021841, SYS_C0021844    T2_STATES, T3_CITIES, T4_CUSTOMERS  Select Count(*) "ROWS_WHERE_MARKET_ID_IS_1" From T1_MARKETS Where MARKET_ID = 1
USER_1  T2_STATES               5   T3_CITIES, T4_CUSTOMERS             SYS_C0021842, SYS_C0021845                  null                                Select Count(*) "ROWS_WHERE_MARKET_ID_IS_1" From T2_STATES Where MARKET_ID = 1
USER_1  T3_CITIES               7   T4_CUSTOMERS                        SYS_C0021846                                null                                Select Count(*) "ROWS_WHERE_MARKET_ID_IS_1" From T3_CITIES Where MARKET_ID = 1
USER_1  T4_CUSTOMERS            5   NULL                                null                                        null                                Select Count(*) "ROWS_WHERE_MARKET_ID_IS_1" From T4_CUSTOMERS Where MARKET_ID = 1
*/
```

LISTAGG(Distinct ...) probably doesn't work with 10g - it is here just to describe interconnections and you don't need it.
PL/SQL code with Cursor declared from the above code....

```sql
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
Declare
    CURSOR c IS
       WITH
          grid AS
                ... code from above ...;
    cSet c%ROWTYPE;
    Counter Number := 0;
    NumRows Number := 0;
    DataRow VarChar2(80);
Begin
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ID' || '  ' || RPAD('OWNER', 12, ' ') || '  TABLE_NAME      ROWS_PER_TABLE  NUM_ROWS_1');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('--  ------------  --------------  --------------  ----------');
    OPEN c;
    LOOP
        FETCH c InTo cSet;
        EXIT WHEN c%NOTFOUND;
        Counter := Counter + 1;
        DataRow := '';
        Execute Immediate cSet.SQL_PK_TABLE_MARKET_ID_1_ROWS Into NumRows;
        DataRow := DataRow || LPad(Counter, 3 - Length(Counter), ' ') || LPAD('  ', 3 - Length(Counter), ' ');
        DataRow := DataRow || cSet.OWNER || LPAD('  ', 14 - Length(cSet.OWNER), ' ');
        DataRow := DataRow || cSet."TABLE" || LPAD('  ', 14 - Length(cSet."TABLE"), ' ');
        DataRow := DataRow || LPad(cSet.TABLE_ROWS, 17 - Length(cSet.TABLE_ROWS), ' ');
        DataRow := DataRow || LPad(NumRows, 13 - Length(NumRows), ' ');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(DataRow);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE c;
End;
/
--
--  R e s u l t :
--
--  ID  OWNER         TABLE_NAME      ROWS_PER_TABLE  NUM_ROWS_1
--  --  ------------  --------------  --------------  ----------
--   1  USER_1        T1_MARKETS                   2           1
--   2  USER_1        T2_STATES                    5           3
--   3  USER_1        T3_CITIES                    7           5
--   4  USER_1        T4_CUSTOMERS                 5           3
--  
--  PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

NUM_ROWS_1 column is number of rows per table having MARKET_ID = 1
Hope you could adjust this to your actual context.